# Question about symmetric bilinear form and convex geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sg.symplectic-geometry, convex-geometry

Consider a Finsler norm $\varphi$ in $R^4$, and a positive definite symmetric bilinear form $S$, there also exists a vector-valued symmetric linear form $Q$, such that if $S(v, w) = 0$, then $Q(v, w)$ is tangent to the level surface of Finsler norm $\varphi$ at direction $v$ and $w$.

My question is that: If $Q$ is not identically zero, is this convex body an ellipsoid?

The background of this problem is that I try to generalize a lemma in my master thesis to a higher dimension. The answer is yes for convex body in $R^3$ and here is the proof:

> If we consider the level surface of Finsler norm in $R^3$, for every 2-dimensional
> hyperplane that crosses the origin, there always exists a basis
> $\{e_1, e_2\}$, such that $S(e_1, e_1) = 1, S(e_1, e_2) = 0, S(e_2, e_2) = 1$. This means that $Q(e_1, e_2)$ is tangent to the convex body
> both at $e_1$ and $e_2$.
>
> Now we consider a rotation with $x = cos\alpha, y = sin\alpha$, since
> $S(x e_1 - y e_2, y e_1 + x e_2) = 0$, $Q(x e_1 - y e_2, y e_1 + x e_2) = xy(Q(e_1, e_1) - Q(e_2, e_2)) +(x^2 - y^2)Q(e_1, e_2)$ is
> always tangent at $x e_1 - y e_2$ and $y e_1 + x e_2$ for
> rotation of every angle $\alpha$.
> Then $Q$ would map to $-Q$ when angle $\alpha$ goes from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. So there exists a rotation such that $Q$ lies in the
> tangent plane spanned by $\{e_1, e_2\}$. Since for such a pair of
> vectors $(x_0 e_1 - y_0 e_2, y_0 e_1 + x_0 e_2)$, $Q$ has to be
> tangent at two points of the convex body restricted in 2-dimensional hyperplane. Since smooth convex body is
> symmetric, then $Q$ has to be zero.
>
> So we change the basis of $\{e_1, e_2\}$ to the basis after rotation
> $\{x_0 e_1 - y_0 e_2, y_0 e_1 + x_0 e_2\}$ and denote it as {e_1', e_2'}. Then $Q(e_1', e_2') = 0$. So $Q(e_1', e_1') - Q(e_2', e_2')$
> has to be tangent at every point of the 2-dimensional hyperplane. So
> it is a linear projector that maps the whole convex body to this
> hyperplane.
>
> Then using Kakutani ellipsoid theorem in convex geometry, this convex body has to be an ellipsoid.

The difficulty of generalizing this proof to a higher dimension lies in that for every 2-dimensional hyperplane that crosses the origin, whether there always exists a basis of vectors $(v, w)$ such that the orbit of rotation of $Q(v, w)$ is a 1-dimensional linear subspace. It is possible that it is always 2-dimensional for arbitrary basis.

For sure, there might exist a different proof or there might exist a counterexample.

Comment: There's something missing in your description of your problem.  For example, you don't assume any connection between $S$ and $M$ or put any condition on $Q$.  If you let $S$ and $M$ be arbitrary and just take $Q(v,w) = 0$ for all $v$ and $w$, then your hypotheses are satisfied but $M$ need not be an ellipsoid.  (This is a counterexample to your claim even in dimension $3$.)  Moreover, since there is no connection between $S$ and $M$ assumed, for the basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ that you first construct in your 'proof', there is no reason to suppose that $e_1$ and $e_2$ to belong to $M$.

Comment: @RobertBryant Yes, you are correct. I try to reformulate it but it does not work. It should be below: If $S(v, w) = 0$, then $Q(v, w)$ is tangent to level surface of Finsler norm $\varphi$. It does not matter whether basis lies on convex body $M$.

Secondly, yes, $Q$ cannot be identically zero. The point is that if it is zero for a zero measurable set, then by continuity, Kakutani still holds.

Comment: @RobertBryant Also, this problem originates from my thesis of isometric embedding $f$ of second-order flat Finsler metric into Banach-Minkowski space. S(v, w) is an analog of second fundamental form, using projection of $d_p^2 f(v, w)$ into some fixed vector $\tau$. $Q(v, w) = d_p^2 f(v, w) - S(v, w) \tau $. 
First-order flatness implies that $d_p \varphi(d_p^2 f(v, w)) = 0$. So $d_p \varphi(Q(v, w)) = 0$ if $S(v, w) = 0$. 
We proved that 3-dim second-order flat Finsler manifold embedded into 4-dim Banach-Minkowski space has degenerate second fundamental form. But not sure for higher dim.

Comment: Is the convex body $M$ the set of vectors that satisfy $\phi(v)\le 1$?  Otherwise, you haven't said how $M$ is related to anything else, so I'm guess that this is what you mean.  Let me know if you mean something different.

Comment: @RobertBryant Yes, it is unit sphere of Finsler norm and its interior.